# register bot - what https endpoint to use when developing?

Tags: c#, frameworks, bots

I want to register my bot. So far I have been emulating with http://localhost:SOME_PORT_NUMBER/api/messages/
But this is not accepted in "HTTPS endpoint". Is it really necessary to suscribe the bot to Azure or some other portal to get an endpoint? What are my options?

Comment: Can't you just take out the port number since https utilizes a known port number of 443?

Comment: A connection needs a client application and a server application.  You are running a client application and connecting to a server.  The endpoint is the IP address of the server you are connecting to.  It looks like you are emulating with an non secure server (http) and you real application is secure (https).  You can write your own server emulation application when developing or load the server on your local PC.

Comment: I decided to use Azure and got a new endpoint address as well as new ID and password. Unfortunately, when I run the bot Emulator with these, it answers "Error. the host is remote but the callback URL is localhost" I checked the ngrok settings. Seem fine to me. Is there anything else that might cause this error?